# How to keep fixed a portion of a web page?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm creating a web page with some content which is divided into two sides: a left side and a right side. The right side contains various forms and needs to be scrollable, the left side instead contains only an image and some buttons/checkbox and it needs to stay fixed. Therefore the left side itself cannot be scrolled, but when I scroll the right side, the left side stay fixed and I still can see its content if I am at the top or at the bottom of the page.

In figures, what I am tring to achieve is something like the following:
[image]
In the figure above you can see my main page. The right content is scrollable and when you scroll it the left content stay fixed. At the bottom of the page I can still see the left content as in the following image:
[image]
Is there any way I can achieve this? I'm developing using Angular and Bootstrap, but I'm using also custom CSS.

Comment: Are you saying you weren’t able to find anything in your own research, on such a topic / technique that’s used by so many websites?

Comment: @04FS if I'm writing a question here, no, I didn't, don't you think? It seems that major people on the web want to stick content on some parts of their pages but in my case I want the left side to be always visible when you scroll the right side.

Comment: So, position it fixed then, or apply overflow to the right side only … both everything but _new_ techniques.

Comment: @04FS marking the question as a duplicate of another (if you can find any) or suggest an answer would have been better than useless sarcasm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use  flexbox/css grid or bootstrap grid for drawing basic layout and can use code

```
.left-container{
   position: fixed;
   top: 0; 
   right: 0;
}
```

for better understanding please go through css position properties

In case if your right panel gets distorted once you place fixed position on left div  you can do something like this:

```
 .side-bar{
    width: 20%;
    height: 550px;
    border-right: 2px solid black;
    position: fixed;
}

.main{
    width: 80%;
    height: 550px;
    margin-left: 20%;
}
```

place margin left of main /right div to the width of left panel, like I have width of side panel as 20% so I have placed margin-left of main div to 20%

Comment: position: fixed is what I want indeed, but in my case, when I stick the content, the layout messes up.

Comment: This is because once you fix the position of an element, it moves out of normal flow of document, so the space is available for other elements to fill in

Comment: Oh, I see, but what if I don't want this behavior and I'd like to stick an element and make the space not available, so - for instance - keeping the style I designed?

Comment: You can do something like this then.side-bar{
    width: 20%;
    height: 550px;
    border-right: 2px solid black;
    position: fixed;
}

.main{
    width: 80%;
    height: 550px;
    margin-left: 20%;
}, I have updated my answer, please try that, it was working for me

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="image-container">
  //add your html code here
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.image-container {
   position: fixed;
   top: 0; 
   right: 0;
   display: block;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix your container use `position:fixed`

[here](https://codepen.io/Wulfor/pen/wZxPrr) is a project that i did that has fixed position on left.